# Showing that $\frac{1}{f_n} \to \frac{1}{f}$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

**Exercise** Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on an interval $I$ and that there is a positive constant $M$ such that $f_n(x) \geq M$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in I$. Show that $\{\frac{1}{f_n}\}$ converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{f}$ on $I$.

---

*Proof Attempt*

Since $f_n(x) \geq M \hspace{0.2cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall x \in I$, we have that

$$\frac{1}{f_n(x)} \leq \frac{1}{M}$$

Consider the constant sequence $ \langle C_1, C_2, C_3, \dots \rangle = \langle \frac{1}{M}, \frac{1}{M}, \dots \rangle$

By our hypothesis, for each constant $C_k \in \{C_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, we have

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, \forall x \in I, \hspace{0.2cm} \frac{1}{f_n(x)} \leq C_k$$

---

To me, it would seem beneficial to use the Weierstrass $M$-Test here so that we could conclude that the $\frac{1}{f_n}$'s are uniformly Cauchy, and thus uniformly convergent. The only glaring issue is that there is no way to guarantee that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty C_k < \infty$. Am I taking this proof in the right direction? Is the $M$-test applicable here?

Comment: Here is a suggestion to get started: Try starting with the difference $|\frac1{f(x)}-\frac{1}{f_n(x)}|$ and see if you can figure out a way to choose $n$ large enough (independently of $x$) so that this is less than $1$. The $M$-test applies to uniform convergence for series, so you would have to find a way to introduce a series in order to make an approach based off the $M$-test work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uniform convergence we have equivalent condition
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_I|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$
Now considering
$$\left|\frac{1}{f_n}- \frac{1}{f_n} \right|=\left|\frac{f_n-f}{f_nf} \right|$$
we have needed estimation, because $f\geqslant M$ together with $f_n$.

Comment: I like this approach to the problem, but where does $M$ come into play? Like you said, $f \geqslant M$ but what does that tell us?

Comment: @Sunroad2 You need to say something to say about the denominator $f_n f$.

Comment: @SunRoad2 To be more explicit,  you need the denominator to be bound away from 0

Comment: Agreeing with above comments let me write $ff_n\geqslant M^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{ff_n}\leqslant \frac{1}{M^2 }$.